# How do I remove Timeline from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I visited my friend's profile on Facebook recently. Impressed with his Timeline feature I added to my profile as well. Bored with it, I want to get rid of the Timeline now.

How can I remove it? I was unable to find it in my *Account* settings, under *Apps*.

Comment: Word on the street is that eventually every Facebook profile will be forced to become a Timeline anyway, so even if you *could* deactivate it, it wouldn't be for long.

Comment: I'm a bit curious as to how you become bored with your timeline but excited about your old profile?

Answer (score 15):

You [can't deactivate](http://www.slashgear.com/beware-facebook-timeline-theres-no-going-back-16202898/) Timeline once you've activated it.

> As for Facebook’s help pages, there’s no reference given to turning off Timeline. In fact, the only conversion reference is if you accidentally switch your Timeline to a business page, something which requires contacting Facebook support to rectify.
>
> […]
>
> Facebook has confirmed to us that there is no way to return to the old-style profile once you have switched to Timeline.

Comment: Moreover, [watch out for scammers](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/01/03/timeline-related-scams-develop-on-facebook/)!

Answer (score 2):

You can actually deactivate Facebook Timeline, and it does work. The instructions are here: http://fbpurity.com/disable-facebook-timeline.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style layout of your Facebook i.e. pseudo-deactivate Timeline wherever it appears on Facebook with this chrome extension

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nkcokgbocjdimlmboepiomecihakbinp/

It doesn't work for Facebook pages.