# How do I opt out of Timeline?

Tags: facebook-timeline

> **Related**:
>   [How do I remove Timeline from Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22139/how-do-i-remove-timeline-from-facebook)

How do I opt out of Timeline?

I did not request Timeline but however I now have it and had a message said it would be visible to my friends on the 23rd. I do not want Timeline as I find it scrambled and hard to follow.

Comment: sadly you cannot! please don't click the links which says _how to remove fb timeline_! You'll be trapped

Comment: That's easy: just stop using Facebook. Facebook, like every other free service that you use, sets the rules about what features it provides, and what format it provides them. If you don't like their rule-change, then you simply move to a new service that you do like.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook is rolling out Timeline to everyone, and there is no way to stick with the old style of Facebook after they have transitioned your account.

Answer (score 5):

You don’t. It will become mandatory.

> Over the next few months, **anyone still refusing to voluntarily switch to the Timeline profile redesign will be automatically migrated**, Facebook tells me. Users could choose to adopt the redesign starting in January, but there have been some hold-outs who didn’t want their whole life becoming easier to access, or just hated change.

[Source](http://techcrunch.com/2012/07/30/switch-to-timeline/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove Timeline. Once it has been enabled on your account, it is there permanently. The only thing that you can do is restyle how it is displayed in your own web browser. For instance, if you don’t like the double column layout, you can view it in a single column layout, using the FB Purity browser extension, which you can get here: http://fbpurity.com